# Why HTML5 Web Worker have to be initialized within a HTML file in Chrome Browser?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web-worker

I just made a script for a web-worker and wondered whether this is another bug chrome-browser suffers from. 
I do not know whether another chromium-bug has been fixed already because you could not initialized another worker(nested) within a running worker in chromium:
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=31666

This in the main.html:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="workerScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" src="workerScript2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>

    // no error is thrown when workerScript.init('workerScript2.js') is called
    console.log(workerScript.init('workerScript2.js')); // Worker { ... }

</script>
```

workerScript.js:

```
function callWorker(){
    var worker = new Worker('workerScript.js');
}

callWorker(); // Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined
```

workerScript2:

```
var workerScript = {
  init: function(file){
    var worker = new Worker(file);
    return worker;
  }
};
```

When main.html is executed in chromium(version 40.0.2214.91 m) 
an error is thrown in workerScript.js:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Worker is not defined

In chromiums it seems that as long as you initialize a worker in an executed html-file no error is thrown except **within** an external js-file when a function is called or new Worker(...) is executed as it is the case in workerScript.js.

Actuall question:
Is this a security-issue/precaution of chromium because if no error was thrown would workerScript.js be an infinite loop in chromium?(a worker in workerScript.js tries to open workerScript.js again?) But why is this working in other browsers like Firefox or even IE?

Comment: "except within an external js-file when a function is called or new Worker" - No, only a worker. Your question (except the last question) is already answered by the issue that you've linked. From the quote, it is not apparent whether you understand what a Worker is, in terms of execution context and available APIs. Given that the question has already been answered in the linked issue, what else do you want/need to know?

Comment: I use worker quite a while, but I do not know whether is a difference between an initzalized nested-worker in a separete file or within a running worker. If chrome makes no difference then you have deserved my points, but I'm not sure about that.

Comment: The behavior of the Worker constructor does not differ for scripts in a .js and .html file. The possibly confusing part in your question is that you've loaded the same script twice, first as an external .js file, then as the entry point for a Web Worker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the comments provided by **Rob W** it's the same bug described at the top of the question.

Hopefully this bug is going to be fixed anytime soon. Because I've got to check whether it's a chrome-browser and if so only running **one** main-worker instead of several nested-workers. Chrome is fast but in terms of computing with workers it could be made faster.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

As of 9/8/16 this has not been resolved. We recently had a few comments on the thread (link in OP), but still no traction. There is a larger issue that android/safari don't support shared workers at all. There is a nice workaround involving shuttling the worker thread data between them, but this ties up the main thread... and isn't supported (last I checked) in Firefox (woo).